# How to force onStartCommand to run before onCreate

Tags: android

I really appreciate if anybody helps me with this issue.
I have two Services, the first one send data to the second service using Intent. As it is a Service I used below code to get extras:

```
  @Override
  public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

    theme = intent.getExtras().getInt("theme");
    Log.v("pos1 : ", String.valueOf(theme));

   return START_STICKY;
   }
```

and right after that the onCreate() is declared.

```
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if(theme != 0)
        // do something
    Log.v("pos2 : ", String.valueOf(theme));
    }
```

But the variable "theme" remain equal to zero until all tasks on onCreate() perform. then onStartCommand() executes.
The results of debugging are something like this

```
pos2 : 0
pos1 : 5 (the value that have sent from first service)
```

Comment: This is impossible. The operating system calls `onCreate()` after it instantiates your Service class, then it starts delivering start commands.

Comment: @Karakure Unfortunately this is what happens. I traced it line by line and found out that the system calls `onStartCommand()` after `onCreate() finishs`

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. I am saying it is impossible to do what you want because the system always calls `onCreate()` first, before it starts delivering start commands. There is no way to have it do the opposite.

Comment: @karakuri oh. thank you for your explanation. however, do you have any idea to pass data from `Service` to `Service` and use in `onCreate` ?

Comment: As I said, you can't. Whatever you want to do with that data, you have to do in `onStartCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did, well I just removed onCreate method and then i m getting my passed String to OnStartCommand.

As i was using MediaPlayer service, where the service was creating media player in OnCreate, then i shifted my Media Player Create to OnStartCommand and removed OnCreate Method.

```
if (view == play) {
                String newstring= "Hello.mp3";
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), BackgroundAudioService.class);
                serviceIntent.putExtra("NewSong", newstring);
                getActivity().startService(serviceIntent);
                play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

And then i get the date in OnStartCommand

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        ChalisaName= intent.getStringExtra("NewSong");
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplication(),  Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/MyPath/" + NewSong));
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        return START_STICKY;

    }
```